# SilverStripe hide default pagetypes

Tags: silverstripe

I'm trying to understand the **best practice** method of hiding SilverStripe's default pagetypes eg **Virtual Page**

I'm assuming the code for these pagetypes are buried in the core, which I rather leave untouched. Therefore I've found this method to work:

`class HidePageType_VirtualPage extends Page implements HiddenClass {
   static $hide_ancestor = 'VirtualPage';
}`

Although this seems to be the cleanest and least hacky solution, I still wonder if anyone has a better way. Besides, this method is creating a new database column based on the class name, which doesn't make sense considering the goal of **hiding a pagetype**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a better Solution, but I'd just create an extension that returns `false` in the `canCreate` method. Example:

```
class CantCreateExtension extends DataExtension
{
    public function canCreate($member)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then apply it to the Pages you don't want to be created, by adding the following to your `_config.yml`:

```
VirtualPage:
  extensions:
    - CantCreateExtension
```

Comment: Cheers, this does the same job (hide pagetype from create-page-dropdown) without the database additions, great solution. I tried the same but instead of `DataExtension` I wrote `VirtualPageExtension` and got a 500 error.

Comment: As a follow-up question: I want admins to be able to see, create and edit the error page, however completely hide it from the CMS SiteTree for `content_authors` aka normal users. I tried the same but using `canView`, but the page is still visible in the SiteTree. I believe `canView` only disables actually opening the page (which oddly results in a 500 error now, with canView set to false).

Comment: @Faloude you need to override both "canView" and "canEdit"… that should work.

Comment: Thanks again. You're right, the page icons are transparent now and not clickable anymore for content authors. Ideally I would rather have it hidden completely, but I guess that's not possible without getting into the cms css right?

Comment: @Faloude Yeah, you could add a custom CSS file to hide them completely. You can do that easily via config settings, see: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/customising_the_admin_interface/how_tos/extend_cms_interface/#include-custom-css-in-the-cms

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution from the original post, updated for SilverStripe 4:

```
<?php

use SilverStripe\CMS\Model\VirtualPage;
use SilverStripe\ORM\HiddenClass;

class HideVirtualPage extends VirtualPage implements HiddenClass {
    private static $hide_ancestor = 'SilverStripe\CMS\Model\VirtualPage';
}
```

As far as I know this is still the only way to block it from everyone including admins (other than hiding it with CSS).  Hopefully a future version of the framework will be adding a $hide_self config var or similar.